# Detecting two arduinos coming in proximity of each other

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rf, wireless

I want to hook up LEDs to two arduinos and then have them turn their LEDs on if they are within about 3 feet of each other, what module would I use to detect this? I was thinking NFC like a RFID but those usually need to be as close as 10cm.

Bonus if I could also access the received signal strength.

Could I do this with two esp8266 using one as an ad hoc Network and attempting to connect with the other one? Would I like that give me received signal strength?

I want one to be worn by me and one by another person and when we get in some proximity have the Arduinos know and do stuff

Comment: Maybe the Bluetooth 4.0 [proximity profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Proximity_sensing) is an option? See [an Adafruit introduction](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy?view=all) [and the spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=303199). You should specify the constrains (use case / context) of your application, it probably helps finding the best suited technology.

Comment: There really isn't much constraints other than id like it to be somewhat easy to set up. Will BLE be able to detect when the other device comes in range or out of it and auto connect?